# PHP function always returning false

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am looking to figure out why the returned result is always `false`

The SQL and PHP code is the following:

```
public function getAlbumList($userID){
    $albumIDs= mysql_query("SELECT albumID FROM albumAccess WHERE userID='$userID'");
    //$albums = mysql_query("SELECT albums.* FROM albums WHERE albumAccess.userID = '$userID' AND albumAcess.albumID = albums.albumID");

    if($albumIDs){
        $albums=array();

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
            $albums[]=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '$r'");     
        }
        return mysql_fetch_array($albums);

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

The PHP code taking the result and passing it to android app is this:

```
$userID=$_POST['userID'];

        $albumList = $db->getAlbumList($userID);

        if($albumList){
            $response["success"]=1;
            $response['album']=array();     
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($albumList)){
                $response['album'][]= $r;                   
            }

            header('Content-type: text/json');
            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            //album list failed to be loaded
            $response["error"]=2;
            $response["error_msg"]="Error Loading Album List. Please try again later.";

            header('Content-type: text/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

When I check the log of what is returned back I always get the error message

> "Error loading album list"

However, I only get that when I am attempting to return back the array. If I just return `true` without using the second SQL requset it returns back true.

Comment: First, are you sure there's anything to actually return? Also, maybe add a "or die(json_encode(array('errors' => array('Internal issue:' => mysql_error($conn)))));" after the mysql_query to see if there's an issue with the database connection

Comment: Yes I am looking at the tables and making sure the userID sent matches what is there and the albumID as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to use a JOIN or SUBQUERY:

```
public function getAlbumList($userID){
    $albumIDs= mysql_query("SELECT *
                            FROM albums
                            WHERE albumID IN (
                               SELECT albumID FROM albumAccess WHERE userID='$userID'
                            )");

    if(mysql_numrows($albumIDs) > 0){
        $albums=array();

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
            $albums[] = $r;    
        }

        return $albums;
    }

    return false;
}
```

PHP code:

```
    $albumList = $db->getAlbumList($userID);

    if($albumList){
        $response["success"]=1;
        $response['album'] = $albumList;
    } else {
        //album list failed to be loaded
        $response["error"]=2;
        $response["error_msg"]="Error Loading Album List. Please try again later.";
    }   
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I now get a success however my array is coming out to be 0

Comment: Oh, let me change the display section of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here, look at this change

```
$albumIDs= mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT albumID FROM albumAccess WHERE userID='$userID'"));  //changed this line

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
           $row=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '$r'");
         $albums[]=mysql_fetch_row($row);  //added this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the first function:

```
public function getAlbumList($userID){
    $albumIDs= mysql_query("SELECT albumID FROM albumAccess WHERE userID='$userID'");
    //$albums = mysql_query("SELECT albums.* FROM albums WHERE albumAccess.userID = '$userID' AND albumAcess.albumID = albums.albumID");

    if($albumIDs){
        $albums=array();

        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
            $statement=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '$r'");   
            $albums[]=mysql_fetch_row($statement); 
        }
        return $albums;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

The following row get user id not correctly:

```
$albums[]=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '$r'");
```

but you must use:

```
$albums[]=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '".$r['albumID']."'");
```

At the and change this:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
    $statement=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '$r'");   
    $albums[]=mysql_fetch_row($statement); 
}
return $albums;
```

Bye!
Marco

Comment: Is there nothing wrong with the second part? I am still getting the same error message which means what it is returning is coming out false

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
public function getAlbumList($userID){
  $albumIDs= mysql_query("SELECT albumID FROM albumAccess WHERE userID='$userID'");


if($albumIDs){
    $albums=array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($albumsIDs)){
        $second = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE albumID = '".$r['albumID']."' ");  
         $alb = mysql_fetch_array($second) ;
        $albums[]= $alb['your_column_you_want_fetch'];  
    }
    return $albums;

}else{
    return false;
}

}
```